# Wordpress admin area used to administer other site

Tags: admin

I have one idea and I'm just thinking about pros/cons.

I have a website powered by PHP and need to recreate its admin area. I'm thinking to do that in Wordpress... I mean to install wordpress and plugins for it which will be used to admin the other site. There are several advantages e.g. very easy to create new features (admin pages), admins/roles management (there are more admins already with different privileges needed) and so on.

What do you think about this ? I know there is no exact answer for this but your opinion helps me to get decision.

Comment: Can you explain your site and what type of content it has? Can you give the URL?

Answer (score 1):

I am honestly not sure if this is a good idea. You can probably get it working but it feels more like a working against the system rather than natural synergy.

Had you considered just migrating site to WordPress?

By the way take a look at [BackPress](http://backpress.org/) - some of related WordPress features, abstracted into standalone framework.

Comment: This site is quite popular with over 100K visitors/day and is highly optimized for what it does as it is custom made. Also front-end doesn't need any modifications, runs fast and is stable, but Admin are of site needs to be changed and need more features like admin roles and so on. So this is why I think about to move it to WP admin area. BackPress seems to be interesting idea, but it probably doesn't contain admin interface. I mean graphical presentation of admin area, or am I missing something ?